# Format JSON String in JSP

Tags: json

I have started working on JSON, I am returning a JSON from JSP through AJAX call. Its working well.

only i need to change the format of my returning JSON String.

Following is the String what my JSP is returing.

```
[{"VV":0,"desc":"XXXXXXX","amount":0,"date":"12/03/2013","watch":""},{"VV":1,"desc":"XXXXXXX","amount":1,"date":"12/03/2013","watch":""}]
```

and Below is the String what I want my JSP to return.

```
{"total":"2","rows":[{"VV":0,"desc":"XXXXXXX","amount":0,"date":"12/03/2013","watch":""},{"VV":1,"desc":"XXXXXXX","amount":1,"date":"12/03/2013","watch":""}] }
```

Can Any one please help.

Following code I am using to send the output back to front end.

```
JSONArray arrayObj=new JSONArray();

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
  json.put("VV", i);
  json.put("desc", "XXXXXXXXX");
  json.put("amount", 1);  
  json.put("date", "12/03/2013");
  json.put("watch", "");

PrintWriter out1 = response.getWriter();
  out1.println(arrayObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to so with the "json" object that you have created is to allocate to a new variable. Something like this:

```
arrayObj.put(json);
```

Next you need to create another object:

```
JSONObject finalObj = new JSONObject();
finalObj.put("total", 2);
finalObj.put("rows",arrayObj);
finalObj.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert it to String and override the toString() method according to your needs and pass it to your JSP page